# How do I install the Export/Import Tool in Opencart 2.0.1.1

Tags: php, ftp, opencart, opencart2.x, cwd

How can I use the Export/Import Tool extension in Opencart Version 2.0.1.1?

I tried merging the upload folder contents. However, nothing seemed to change. No extra menus, nothing. I tried to use the extension installer too. That did not work out well.

At first, opencart was asking for FTP settings. I installed filezilla server and set it up locally with wamp. However, it showed that current working directory was not found while using those FTP settings.

```
 CWD 
    C:\wamp\www\wasp
```

Then I tried simply merging the files by moving those admin and system folder in my opencart installation. Nothing happened.

Comment: Is the Export/Import Tool extension for Opencart 2?

Comment: Code formatting by indenting 4 spaces (Ctrl+K on the block), otherwise a `>` introduces a quoted text in this system. Try to break some lines to prevent wall-of-text effects.

Comment: Please read the readme.txt comes along with extension.

Comment: I was able to use the extension by disabling the FTP requirement for extension upload. I used this extension as instructed in the read-me doc with a fresh Opencart installation. That worked. 
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=18892

Comment: @B-and-P Yes, Opencart Version 2.0.1.1 .

Comment: Would you like to provide the extension url which you used?

Comment: I did already! Check this out.
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=18892